# Program window not viewable during debug pause

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

When my program is paused in Visual Studios 2010 during debugging, like from reaching a break point and me doing a manual step through, the program window becomes impossible to view.

It is a GUI window not a console window, which I run simultaneously with my program and am still able to view. The window seems to be open it's just that when I click its icon on the taskbar it doesn't come to the front of all the other windows. When I minimize all the windows in front of it, I see the outline of the window but it is either blacked out or showing the remnants of previously expanded windows.

I've noticed this with using Visual Studio's before (various versions of it), and after trying other IDE's that didn't have this behavior I notice it more. It would be really helpful to view the program's change's as I step through the program. Anyone know how I can do this?

I searched a long while and couldn't find a single reference to this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the window doesn't display is that the window paint message won't be processed if the main thread has been paused.  Which other IDEs let you do this?  I haven't come across any native code debuggers that do this on Windows.

Comment: Actually the other IDEs were on ubuntu. xD

Comment: Presumably the X11 system for painting works in quite a different way to on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stepping through code that is run by the main thread, then the main thread can't simultaniously poll the message pump, which is needed for the GUI to work.

If you debug a different thread, the GUI will work while you are debugging.